# htaccess/cPanel 301 redirects not working for add-on domain

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, cpanel

I've already looked at many samples and tutorials how to set up those 301 redirects on Apache and can't figure out why some are not working. Whenever I want to redirect any still existing page from the old domain to the new domain the page on the old domain is still used. But it "works" if you type in a page which does not exist on the old domain. The same is true for directories which do not exist on the old domain. So whenever you type a non-existing URL (page or folder) the redirections is taking place (but of course produces 404 errors of on the new domain).

In addition it also works for the domain name itself. So just typing "old.com" correctly redirects to "new.com".

Any input is much appreciated because this is slowly driving me crazy :)

**EDIT:** I added the complete htaccess file.

**EDIT 2:** So I removed almost all redirects and currently my htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.new.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

The only redirect that is working is the simple one from old.com to new.com. A redirect like old.com/page.htm to new.com or even new.com/page.htm is not working.

**EDIT 3:** This is the .htaccess of the top-level domain:

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName www.toplvl.com
AuthUserFile /home2/a_user/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home2/a_user/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toplvl.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.toplvl.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.toplvl.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: "only the second one is working" - The comments in your code block seem to suggest that #2, #3 and #4 are working? Just to note, the `RewriteRule` substitution (2nd argument) is a normal string, not a regular expression, so ordinarily you do not need to escape anything or surround it in double quotes. You've tagged your question `cPanel` - however, I assume you aren't using cPanel to apply these redirects (cPanel is likely to cause more problems)?

Comment: Just to clarify... you have no other .htaccess files in subdirectories? And this .htaccess file is in your document root? (Bizarrely, I seem to remember another question recently that had the same problem... `old.com` to `new.com` worked OK, but `old.com/page` to `new.com/page` didn't - I can't find it though at the mo.)

Comment: For this add-on domain I have no other .htaccess files on other subdirectories. For the "main" domain, which is the paren folder for the add-on domain, I have an .htaccess in the folder of the top domain. Regarding cPanel: originally I added the redirects using the cPanel tool, however this didn't work so I started to edit the file manually.

Comment: "I have an .htaccess in the folder of the top domain" - the .htaccess file for the main domain is likely being processed before the .htaccess file for the addon domain (which, in this case, is located in a subdirectory). Double check this by setting an environment variable in the .htaccess file and printing this to your page. If this is the case then the .htaccess file for your top domain might be conflicting.

Comment: Since this is an addon domain pointing to a subdirectory off the main account you will need to add the contents of the ".htaccess in the folder of the top domain" to your question. Can you also define "not working"? a) Nothing happens b) Error c) Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Do you have FrontPage extensions installed?! If so, I have heard of conflicts, but nothing specific I'm afraid.

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of your httpd.conf for the domain.

Comment: I was already searching for the httpd.conf file on the server (using the FTP access) with no luck. I will give it another try.

Comment: @Clemens: You will not be able to access httpd.conf over FTP. The httpd.conf file is the Apache server configuration file and will only be accessible if you have direct access to the server (ie. not a shared host).

Comment: @w3d I was afraid that this is the case. Unfortunately the web hoster of the old domain doesn't respond anymore and this is also the reason why I wanted to add the redirections (and it is a shared host).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should not enclose your new.com with quotes "", neither scape it because your regular expression is inside RewriteCond, not inside the target.

Try something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$
RewriteRule ^some\-page\.php$ http://www.new.com/some-other-page.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Edit: I've added specific url redirection.

As you can see, order matters, is you have something specific you should place it upfront other rules that are more generic like host redirection.

If you need to play a little bit with htaccess you should use a tester [like this](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).
You have to enter urls like http://www.old.com/somepage.php, or http://www.old.com, always using http://.

Comment: Your example seems to imply that the `RewriteCond` directives applies to both `RewriteRule` directives that follow - this is not the case. The `RewriteCond` only applies to the first `RewriteRule`. So, the code as it stands will result in a rewrite loop.

Comment: Hi @w3d, I've tested it, it does not result in rewrite loop because the L(ast) option.

Comment: The `L` option (on the last rule) is irrelevant here. Whether this results in a rewrite loop is dependent on how the add-on domain is setup. If the two domains point to the same place, which is what I assumed, as otherwise there is no need to check the `%{HTTP_HOST}` - then the second `RewriteRule` will result in a rewrite loop (since `old.com` and `new.com` are being served the same .htaccess). If the add-on domain points to an entirely different location then you are right, there is no loop, but the `RewriteCond` directives are not reqd in this case. We would need the OP to confirm this.

Comment: I agree on "*L* opttion (on the last rule) is irrelevant", of course, there is nothing more, in this example it's the end of htaccess, I'm used to write it like that because maybe I'm lazy and I don't want to review working rules if I have to add more at the end.

Comment: The add-on domain is located in a subfolder of a different "main" domain. And yes, this domain has also a .htaccess file.

Comment: @Binarysurf Your suggested rule checker says that the URL would be correctly redirected. But I guess the reason that the redirects are not working is some other configuration I'm not aware of and unfortunately I have no idea where to look.